# Why do I get java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when deploying app?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I am trying to deploy web application on my machine. It is doesn't my app. And when I attempted, I got - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset:

```
WARNING *********** NetBeans HTTP Monitor ************
The request cannot be recorded most likely because the NetBeans HTTP Monitor module is disabled.
MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
NotifyUtil::java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3335)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.NotifyUtil$RecordSender.run(NotifyUtil.java:299)
```

I am using Netbeans and Tomcat, so I tried to deploy this app without IDE, using only Tomcat, but app did not work again.

For example, other apps, which i created or downloaded, work fine.
Please, help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using IDEA.